# Should I reattach textures to framebuffer after resizing

Tags: opengl

Does resizing of textures that are currently attached to framebuffer invalidates what framebuffer is currently pointing to?
In other words should I reattach framebuffer texture with glFramebufferTexture2D call after resizing of texture with glTexImage2D call? Does framebuffer remembers attachment by texture name or directly by it's content (that is obviously invalid after resizing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not resize textures at all; if you need textures of a different size, you should delete them and create a new one.

That being said, everything will work if you rebuild the storage for a texture while it is bound to an FBO.